# Managing access to a file with a direct link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app where I upload files. I'm using gem cancan for managing access to files. The files are stored on the disk. Is it possible to manage access to a file or  restrict/allow it **even when** a user has a **direct** link to it?  Note I'm not using nginx or apache, it's a local application, therefore at best it's unicorn or simply the standard Rails web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Move your files out of `public` folder, which is served by by your web server, to some other folder (`private` for example) and use [send_file](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file) in controller to transmit data. Some pseudo-code for controller:

```
def get_file
  absolute_path = Rails.root + 'private' + params[:filepath]

  if current_user.allowed_to_download?(params[:filepath]) && File.exists?(absolute_path)        
    send_file absolute_path, status: 200 # ok
  else
    render status: 403 # forbidden
  end
end
```

You will have to setup route for this action, but basicly that's all.

Comment: that makes sense. have you tested it?